# Independent random sample problem

Tags: probability, solution-verification, random-variables, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $\{X_i\}$ be a random sample, where each $X_i$ is independent and distributed according to the following:

$$p(x)= \begin{cases}
0.5, if -1 \leq x\leq 1\\
0, otherwise
\end{cases}$$

(i) Is $X_i$ normally distributed? Explain.

(ii) What is the mean and variance of $X_i$?

(iii) Suppose we let $Y_i = X_i - X_{i - 1}$. Compute $E[Y_i]$ and $Var(Y_i)$.

(iv) Would your answers to (iii) above change if $X_i$ and $X_{i - 1}$ were not independent? Justify.

My attempt:

(i) Not sure. Can anybody explain?

(ii) If $-1\leq x\leq 1$, then $E[X_i]= \int_{-1}^{1} 0.5x \,dx = 0$, $E[X_i]= \int_{-1}^{1} 0.5x^2 \,dx = \frac{1}{3}$ and so $Var(X) = \frac{1}{3}$. Otherwise, $E[X_i] = 0$ and $Var(X) = 0$.

(iii) We have $E[Y_i] = E[X_i - X_{i - 1}] = E[X_i] - E[X_{i - 1}] = E[X_i] - E[X_i] = 0$ and $Var[Y_i] = Var(X_i - X_{i - 1}) = Var(X_i) + Var(X_{i - 1}) = Var(X_i) + Var(X_i) = 2Var(X_i)= \begin{cases}
\frac{2}{3}, if -1 \leq x\leq 1\\
0, otherwise
\end{cases}$

(iv) If $X_i$ and $X_i$ are not independent, then the expansion formula for $E[X_i]$ stays the same however formula for $Var(X_i)$ changes because the covariance becomes possibly non-zero. That is, $E[X_i - X_{i - 1}] = E[X_i] - E[X_{i - 1}]$ regardless of whether $X_i$ and $X_{i - 1}$ are independent but $Var(X_i - X_{i - 1}) = Var(X_i) + Var(X_{i - 1}) - 2cov(X_i, X_{i - 1})$ instead. Hence only the variance may change.

Is this correct? I am especially not sure about $(i)$ so any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers for ii) and ii) are are OK. The normal distribution has a specific  strictly positive density on the whole real line ($p(x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi}} e^{-x^{2}/2}$). So the given density function $p$ is not  a normal density function.